# enforcing compile-time checking on runtime annotation

Tags: java

I declare an annotation that should only be used on class properties of primitive type or of java.lang.String type or when the property has been annotated with another annotation @Annot.
How Do i ensure that the user does not annotate the wrong property? who do i enforce rather compile-time checking on the annotations?

Comment: Please clarify your development environment in terms of tools you are using. Ant, maven etc...

Comment: i develop under netbeans platform and i was thinking of something that can be enforced by the java compiler, not plugin tools like maven or ant. but if this is impossible, ant based approach will be acceptable

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotation processing for that. Unfortunately I don't have any experience to share, only [this link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDgQFjAC&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/index.html&rct=j&q=annotation%20processing&ei=c0CdTpTEIcrtOfi3sP4I&usg=AFQjCNEQu01dPGfSXElVf0Zltdlvq1-zIw&sig2=OG6zndRulwsrlms9RfuRRQ&cad=rja) (which may or may not be useful)